# Why are some of the outlets and lights on a breaker not working?

Tags: electrical

House 15A breaker is not tripped but no power in line with 6 outlets and one ceiling light not working, EXCEPT for one light is working and it is closest to the breaker panel. I checked its wiring and it looks fine.

This circuit has no GFCI outlets in it and no grounds in line. House is 66 year old.  Nothing recently occurred in house to cause any change.  I am completely dumbfounded.

Comment: What does "no neutral or grounds in line" mean?

Comment: Just white and black wires, except for operational overhead stove fan and light that have a ground.

Comment: Are the outlets wired with the wires going onto the side-screws, or into the holes in the back?

Comment: No backstabbed outlets, all side screws.

Comment: Found the source of problem. There was a hidden conduit junction box in ceiling under ceiling drywall that contractor 12 years ago covered up. Found loose wire connector and broken wire.

Comment: Thank you to all who helped me troubleshoot this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since you checked the light and it looks fine, check the **first receptacle that doesn't work**. It may have gone "bad", or it may have a loose screw or a backstab connection (which should be moved to a screw connection).

If you are not sure of the sequence of the receptacles, check them all. When nothing has changed (e.g., no construction that could have cut through a wire inside a wall), the problem is at one of the receptacles or other devices in the circuit.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply.  None of them are backstabbed. 
 Using a neon voltage tester I did check power to each wire to each receptacle  and had no power.  I expected and hoped I would find a bad receptacle but no luck. Maybe I should double check again??

Comment: Yes, check again. I'd check the wires coming OUT of the light that works.

Comment: I do have one correction. There is one ground in circuit and  itis for light that works.  This light is part of a fan & light combo over stove and both work ok.

Comment: You need to remove the receptacle and inspect the wiring both on the outlet and any connections made in the box.  Sometimes a connection point fails.

Comment: There are no wires coming out of light connection that works.

Comment: Check the switch for that light. If the power is running panel->[split to]->switch/light and ->other receptacles, then the problem could be a loose connection at the switch.

Comment: The switch on light and on fan over stove both have good connections and this is a separate stand alone line with no outgoing wires.

Comment: Aha. I should have realized from the other descriptions that this isn't "wall switch" but rather an appliance with a built-in switch. So much for that idea.

Comment: To complicate matters, it appears I have some induced voltage in outlets as my min 80 V tester lights up at all outlets but none work. When I plug in adapter for clock radio which requires 500mA, the induced voltage disappears. Crazy bonus complication.

Comment: The phantom voltage is not that unusual and is not, in and of itself, necessary a problem. But it may be a clue.

Comment: @StuballRetired yeah, just suppress that phantom voltage by plugging a nightlight or whatever into 1 socket.   Bonus points, stick high-value resistors into 2-prong plugs, 33K, a 39K, 47K, 56K etc. Then if you measure 0V somewhere you can check the resistance, and if it's exactly 39K, you know the line is good to the resistor.